# How to modify "Merge pull request #... from ..." commit in git history?

Tags: git, github

I merged a pull request in the past then it automatic created a commit:`"Merge pull request #... from ..."`.
I have pushed some other commits to this project.
Now, i want to modify the text(`Merge pull request #... from ...`) of that commit, but i cannot find that commit with `git rebase -i`.
How can i find and modify it?